# Can't successfully do a Release build on "hello, world"

Tags: xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I have written a clean app (Hello, World) which builds correctly using Debug|Simulator and Release|Simulator configurations.  When I try to build using any of the Release configurations, it errors out, saying "No output".

Where do I start looking?  (it can't get any simpler than Hello, World, can it?)

Comment: post your code, you might be overlooking something.

Comment: Post your build output after you add the "Extra Arguments" of -v -v -v

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions... will post tonight after work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected if you have built it with release mode and haven't used the provisioning license but the production one (Apple won't let you distribute across phones this way, you need to do it 'adhoc').

Try rebuilding with the provisioning license and it should deploy correctly.

Comment: I am doing the build with the Ad Hoc provisioning profile... here is the build output:  http://monobin.com/__m6fc09f26

Comment: @user51 looks like a problem for Geoff Norton and the MT team then

Answer (score 0):

I got that fixed (had moved Xcode into the Apps folder!)... now I'm getting a new message "unable to find output file".  I have to  go to work now, so I will update this when I get home.  I have all the screen shots and will generate the output (-v -v -v) and send you the url's where you can find everything.  By the way, this happens on Hello, World in addition to my first app.

Thank you so much for your help... I have been fighting this for over 3 weeks now, and really, really want to get my first app submitted.

Comment: After the solution build, this is the error I'm getting:

error: unable to open executable '/Users/rolfmarsh/iPhoneProjects/BookPricing/bin/iPhone/Release/BookPricing.app/bookPricing'
 (1) (BookPricing)

You can find the output from the above build at: http://pastebin.com/nKLG3ScN

The same thing is happening with a simple Hello, World... the output from that build is at: http://pastebin.com/V2MPd8id

This is very frustrating!

Comment: Quick thought: you're probably better off posting this as a comment or as an edit on your original question.  That's how S.O. keeps track of what might help someone solve their problem and what their problem might be.